# How to use let variable across example blocks without reinitiating the let block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to create FactoryGirl object and use across groups without re-initiating let block multiple times. There should be only one user created in Database. How can i achieve it?

```
describe MyCLass do
  let(:adm) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "test for" do
    #want to use :adm here
  end

  describe "test2 for" do
    #want to use :adm here
  end

  describe "test3" do
    #want to use :adm here
  end
end
```

*I am new to RSpec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best bet is to not use a `let` for this but instead a [`before :all`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks):

```
describe MyCLass do
  before :all do
    @adm = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  describe "test for" do
    @adm.methods_to_test
  end

  describe "test2 for" do
    @adm.methods_to_test
  end

  describe "test3" do
    @adm.methods_to_test
  end
end
```

With that said, **this is likely not a good idea** since it will create interdependent tests which is not what you want! Each test should run in isolation without modified state between tests. Having a "global" user instance will likely cause flapping tests due to test order issues.

Answer (score 1):

> There should be only one user created in database. How can i achieve it?

By cleaning the database after each test. It's the generally recommended approach. Look up DatabaseCleaner gem, for example.